# running petstore webapp from git on docker container using maven

Tags: docker, maven, jetty

I am trying to bundle petstore web application in an image and run it on container. The petstore is maven project.

I created following Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

MAINTAINER Naresh Chaurasia <message4naresh@gmail.com>

RUN apt update

RUN apt install -y openjdk-8-jdk

RUN apt install -y maven

RUN apt install -y git

RUN git clone https://bitbucket.org/connect2tech/connect2tech.in-jpetstore

WORKDIR /connect2tech.in-jpetstore

ENV PATH "$PATH:/usr/bin/mvn"

ENTRYPOINT ["mvn","jetty:run"]
```

The web application is deployed on jetty container on port 8080 by running the following command: `mvn jetty:run`

I am trying to do the same with Dockerfile, but failing to do so.

I might be doing mistake in the following lines, but not able to figure out (since i just getting started with Dockers)

```
ENV PATH "$PATH:/usr/bin/mvn"

ENTRYPOINT ["mvn","jetty:run"]
```

Any guidance/pointer will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

MAINTAINER Naresh Chaurasia <message4naresh@gmail.com>

RUN apt update

RUN apt install -y openjdk-8-jdk maven git

RUN git clone https://bitbucket.org/connect2tech/connect2tech.in-jpetstore

RUN mkdir /connect2tech.in-jpetstore

WORKDIR /connect2tech.in-jpetstore

ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/mvn","jetty:run"]
```

Comment: It works fine. I just had to remove this line ```RUN mkdir /connect2tech.in-jpetstore``` as this folder is already there when git checkout is done.